Menu and action bar not appearing on some devices
My app, based on a FragmentActivity, uses an ActionBar but it appears or not depending on the device it runs on.
With the Android Studio emulators, either running under Android 13 or 14, the ActionBar and the MenuItems I define are correctly displayed.
On an actual Galaxy Tab S6+, running under Android 12, everything is fine as well, but on a phone (Galaxy S24+) and on another tablet (Galaxy Tab S6), both running under Android 14, the ActionBar isn't displayed.
Any idea why this happens?
Compilation parameters :

compile SDK version : 34
build tool version : 35.0.0
java version : 17
min SDK : 26
target SDK : 34
Gradle version : 8.9
Android Gradle plugin version : 8.7.2

My different styles.xml :

V11



<!--
    Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>


V14



<!--
    Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
    res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>


V21



<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="Widget.Memo.AppWidget.Container" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="android:padding">?attr/appWidgetPadding</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/app_widget_background</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Memo.AppWidget.InnerView" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="android:padding">?attr/appWidgetPadding</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/app_widget_inner_view_background</item>
</style>


V31



<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="Widget.Memo.AppWidget.Container" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="android:padding">?attr/appWidgetPadding</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/app_widget_background</item>
<!--    <item name="android:clipToOutline">true</item> -->
</style>

<style name="Widget.Memo.AppWidget.InnerView" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="android:padding">?attr/appWidgetPadding</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/app_widget_inner_view_background</item>
<!--    <item name="android:clipToOutline">true</item> -->
</style>


sw720dp :



<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

<!--  le style pour le texte des articles quand l'article n'est pas coché -->
<style name="TexteNonCoche" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large">
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>  
  
<!--  le style pour le texte des articles quand l'article est coché -->
<style name="TexteCoche" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large">
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#7F7F7F</item>
</style>    


The information provided is merely irrelevant (the parameters); while there is no styles.xml provided. Since you're basically saying it's not there "on a tablet", which may use a different style resource, I'd suggest to make sure to set the proper theme as parent, in all the styles.xml.
This can only be caused by a wrong parent theme or maybe missing tablet styles.
One can also use the Layout Inspector to determine, what's really going on there.
It could also have to do with values-v31 vs. values-v34 ...as you describe it.
Try to put as much as possible into values and only the overrides into there.

'Styles.xml' files contents added

This android:Theme.Light seems suspicious to me ...and also the Holo theme might be useless complexity. And styles-v11 might never be used, when the minimum API level might be 14, which I think is restrained by androidx.
